# Can Grease Pencil 2.8 support transparent background

Tags: export

I try to export grease pencil 2.8 animation by using FFmpeg Video with Quicktime Container, and try out all Video Codec. But still doesnt work. (I already set Render Property-Film with Transparent). Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by using OT Animation Video Codec, then import to Photoshop with transparent background. But there is still another problem, I have set the display and hide some fields in grease pencil, but the video cannot display properly.